# Why the height isn't changed?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a floating menu which floats when you scroll down the page.
[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yugeteze/2)
I also want to increase the menu's height so I've added `height: 70`. Now, I want that the menu would return to be the same when you scroll to top, so I've added `height: nav.height()`.
The code is not working, when you scroll to top the menu doesn't return to his default height value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're setting `nav.height` to `nav.height`, i.e. kind of `a = a` statement: nothing changed between the new value and the old value.

Comment: Very probably there is a bug in your code

Comment: I updated the link, is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the height to 50 when user scrolls to top. When you start scrolling `nav.height()` will be set to 70 and you are using this value when user scrolls again to top.

Try

```
$(function () {

    var nav = $('.navgroups');
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                left: nav.offset().left,
                width: nav.width(),
                height: 70
            });
            isFixed = true;
        } else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                height: 50,//<---------HERE
                position: 'static'
            });
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yugeteze/3/edit)